# continuous error bands with xplot/plotly, in F#

Tags: f#, plotly

I am trying to make a graph like this:

[image]

as explained in the page here: https://plotly.com/python/continuous-error-bars/

the relevant python code is:

```
go.Scatter(
    x=x+x[::-1], # x, then x reversed
    y=y_upper+y_lower[::-1], # upper, then lower reversed
    fill='toself'
)
```

but I'm not so sure how to make the F# equivalent of:

```
y=y_upper+y_lower[::-1]
```

with xplot/plotly

how can I draw a graph like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Plotly.NET for this, actually!

Here's a complete snippet that will reproduce the chart in .NET Interactive.

```
#r "nuget: Plotly.NET.Interactive, 2.0.0-beta9"

open Plotly.NET

let x = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10]
let y = [1; 2; 7; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10]
let y_upper = [2; 3; 8; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; 11]
let y_lower = [0; 1; 5; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9]

Chart.Range(
    x,
    y,
    y_upper,
    y_lower,
    StyleParam.Mode.Lines,
    Color="rgb(0,100,80)",
    RangeColor="rgba(0,100,80,0.2)")
```

The rendering in the documentation stretches the x-axis for some reason, even though I can't see that in the trace itself.

See [range charts](https://plotly.net/2_3_range-plots.html) for more info.

[image]

As for the `y=y_upper+y_lower[::-1]` bit, this is just a list append in F#, so it would be:

`y_upper @ (y_upper |> List.rev)`

But it seems, at least initially, that this may not be necessary if you use Plotly.NET.

Comment: oh ok, so the y data for the upper and lower are appended, with the lower one reversed. I get it! In the meantime, I also came up with an alternative solution: draw the bottom part, then draw the top part with fill = "tonexty" and that seems to work too.